# Example of multi-section Google Form built using Apps Script?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

[Updated to narrow the focus] I can't get a multi-section form built using GAS to build.

Sections are delineated using form.addPageBreakItem, but if you then put in a widget that alters the flow of the sections (such as .addMultipleChoiceItem), it won't build because the section you're navigating to hasn't been defined yet.

Using the .setGoToPage() function has the same issues.

How are these functions supposed to be used to control the flow?

Answer (score 4):

Finally figured it out.  Here's a demo, which is a form to collect tennis match results. (The matches allowed can be short-sets i.e. 5 games)

```js
/*
 * makeMultiForm - Build a multi-sections to collect Singles or Doubles results
 */
function makeMultiForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Match Results Entry')
                    .setConfirmationMessage('Thank you! Your results have been recorded');
  form.setTitle("Demo Tennis Results Form");

  // Start by laying out the bare-bones structure.  This defines the different
  // sections, and the bare widgets in each section.
  // Note that you can't add any flow-routing details at this point, because
  // the destinations most likely haven't been defined yet
  var itemCompetition = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Which Competition");
  var itemMatchDate = form.addDateItem().setTitle("Match Date");
  
  var sectSingles = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Singles Competition");
  var itemPlay1 = form.addListItem().setTitle("Player 1");
  var itemPlay2 = form.addListItem().setTitle("Player 2");
  var itemMatchFormat = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Match Format");

  var sectDoubles = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Doubles Competition");
  var itemTeam1Player1 = form.addListItem().setTitle("Team 1: Player 1");
  var itemTeam1Player2 = form.addListItem().setTitle("Team 1: Player 2");
  var itemTeam2Player1 = form.addListItem().setTitle("Team 2: Player 1");
  var itemTeam2Player2 = form.addListItem().setTitle("Team 2: Player 2");
  var itemMatchFormat2 = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("Match Format");
  
  var sectOneSet = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("5-Games / One Set");
  var itemSet1 = form.addGridItem().setTitle("Score for first set");
  
  var sectTwoSets = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Two Sets");
  var item2SetsSet1 = form.addGridItem().setTitle("Score for first set");
  var item2SetsSet2 = form.addGridItem().setTitle("Score for second set");
  
  // Having defined the bare bones, this adds a jump to the end (submitting
  // the form). Look carefully which section this is - it's not intuitive!
  // The jump is actually defined for section "sectTwoSets", but the 
  // jump is actioned at the end of the section before this one
  sectTwoSets.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
  
  // Now flesh out the contents of the various widgets.  Routing info for
  // the .createChoice methods can now be defined, because all the 
  // variables defining sections have aleady been defined
  itemCompetition.setChoices([
      itemCompetition.createChoice("Singles", sectSingles),
      itemCompetition.createChoice("Doubles", sectDoubles)]);
  itemMatchDate.setRequired(false);
  
  var players = ["Jack", "Gill", "Jim", "Sally"];
  itemPlay1.setChoiceValues(players);
  itemPlay2.setChoiceValues(players);
  itemMatchFormat.setChoices([
      itemMatchFormat.createChoice("5 Games", sectOneSet),
      itemMatchFormat.createChoice("One Set", sectOneSet),
      itemMatchFormat.createChoice("Two Sets", sectTwoSets)]);
  
  itemTeam1Player1.setChoiceValues(players);
  itemTeam1Player2.setChoiceValues(players);
  itemTeam2Player1.setChoiceValues(players);
  itemTeam2Player2.setChoiceValues(players);
  itemMatchFormat2.setChoices([
      itemMatchFormat2.createChoice("5 Games", sectOneSet),
      itemMatchFormat2.createChoice("One Set", sectOneSet),
      itemMatchFormat2.createChoice("Two Sets", sectTwoSets)]);
  
  itemSet1.setRows(["Player 1", "Player 2"])
          .setColumns(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]);

  item2SetsSet1.setRows(["Team 1", "Team 2"])
          .setColumns(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]);
  item2SetsSet2.setRows(["Team 1", "Team 2"])
          .setColumns(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]);
}
```